# Gijgo grid - remove rows

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, grid

I use gijgo from http://gijgo.com/Grid/ for a datatable control. 
The problem is: 
Well... There is a demo for populating datable with json from controller's method. It works. 
http://gijgo.com/Grid/Demos/BasicAjaxCall 
There is a demo for removing rows from a table populated with JSON directly. It works too.
http://gijgo.com/Grid/Methods/removeRow 
But when I try to remove rows from table populated with JSON from controller, it doesn't seem to work. 
http://gijgo.com/LiveEdit/Index/grid.Base.removeRow.sample.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <link href="/Areas/version_0_6/dist/modular/grid/css/grid.base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="/Areas/version_0_6/dist/modular/grid/js/grid.base.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="grid"></table>
 <script>
     var grid;
     function Delete(e) {
         if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
             grid.removeRow(e.data.id);
         }
     }
     grid = $('#grid').grid({
         primaryKey: 'ID',
         dataSource: '/version_0_6/Grid/GetPlayers',
         columns: [
            { field: 'ID', width: 32 },
            { field: 'Name' },
            { field: 'PlaceOfBirth', title: 'Place Of Birth' },
            { title: '', width: 60, align: 'center', tmpl: 'Delete', events: { 'click': Delete } }
         ]
     });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-jQuery-Grid-5239f9c0#content.

The way to do this is to hook a Remove function to the grid and then remove the entry from the database in the controller and then reload.

> Add following to the grid:

```
`{ field: "Delete", title: "", width: 34, type: "icon", icon: "glyphicon-remove", tooltip: "Delete", events: { "click": Remove } }`
```

> Add the Remove function:

`function Remove(e) {
            $.ajax({ url: "Home/Remove", type: "POST", data: { id: e.data.id } })
                .done(function () {
                    grid.reload();
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    alert("Unable to remove.");
                });
        }`

---

To add further, you can still solve this problem by not reloading the entire grid and doing the delete in the database and then calling removeRow for the same row in grid in .done' in the Remove function.

`var deleteRow = gridvars[parentTaskid].getById(event.data.id);
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete Property ID: ' + event.data.id + '?')) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/<Controller>/<action>",
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    data: { id: event.data.id, crossRefId: deleteRow.CrossRefId },
                })
                    .done(function (result) { 
                        //do stuff based on the result
                        gridvars[parentTaskid].removeRow(event.data.id);
                    })
                    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        //do stuff
                    })
            }
            else {
                //do stuff
            }`

FYI: In my example I have multiple such grids (gridvars) on the same page so I have bound them all to the same Remove function.

Comment: So, it is not possible without reloading the grid, right?

Comment: Vivek is right. You need to reload the data in the grid, because the dataSource is located on the backend. You can also try the new development version where the removeRow method is improved. The new version is located at https://github.com/atatanasov/gijgo/tree/development/dist